# Where in the world is com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminTask?

Tags: java, websphere, jython, wsadmin

Frustrated with the damn awful API provided by WebSphere Admin Server, I'm writing my own Java DSL wrapper. My jython files now simply read:

```
from my.package import MyDSL
config = MyDSL(AdminConfig, AdminTask)
config.goGoGadgetSkates() # or something like that
```

The essential part is that I send through the (#%$$!@#) god objects `AdminConfig` and `AdminTask` so that the DSL can use them to perform operations in WAS.

In order to compile the DSL I need to include the class files for this two objects. I find them by first setting the constructor as:

```
public MyDSL(Object a, Object b) {
    System.out.println(a.getClass());
    System.out.println(b.getClass());
}
```

The output showed that the AdminConfig object is an instance of `com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminConfigClient`. I easily located the jar that contains this class and all is well.

But AdminTask is an instance of `com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminTask`. Despite being present at runtime, this class does not exist anywhere in my classpath or indeed anywhere on my computer's hard drive.

I can only assume `com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminTask` is constructed magically by WSAdmin in the jython layer. Perhaps it is defined as a python class?

Before I [resort to reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595782/call-method-via-reflection-when-argument-is-of-type-object), can someone please explain where `com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminTask` might live and how I might extract a copy of the class file?

Comment: Very interesting. I can confirm that with a test JSP to locate classes on the WAS runtime classpath, the former is found but the latter is not. (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/revive_finding_a_java_class_in_your_servlet_container2 )

Comment: This may help you search:

I am not sure that the WAS classpath and that WASadmin's classpath are identical or that they should be.

Anyway, when you have a brand new WebSphere profile, and you start the wsadmin.sh (or .bat) you can see a list of jars it uses. They maybe able to help you.

Comment: google told me, it's not of our world.

Answer (score 1):

The AdminConfigClient class is not API/SPI, so you are creating a fragile infrastructure by relying on that class.  The API/SPI entry point is [ConfigServiceFactory](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/configservice/ConfigServiceFactory.html).

The AdminTask object is backed by the data in [CommandMgr](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/cmdframework/CommandMgr.html).  It should be possible to use CommandMgr to do anything you can do with AdminTask.