# Call method via reflection when argument is of type Object[]

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to call a method on [a class that is dynamically constructed at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578490/where-in-the-world-is-com-ibm-ws-scripting-admincommand-admintask):

```
public String createJDBCProvider(Object[] args)
```

Here's how:

```
Method m = adminTask.getClass().getMethod("createJDBCProvider", Object[].class);
id = (String) m.invoke(adminTask, new Object[]{ "a", "b", "c" });
```

IDEA warns me that I'm guilty of `redundant array creation for calling varargs method`.

The method I'm calling actually takes an `Object[]`, not `Object ...` but they're probably equivalent and interchangeable I think, so I forge ahead.

At runtime I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

So it seems that, perhaps, my `Object[]` is being passed as a sequence of `Object`s. Is this what is happening? If so, how can I coerce it to not do so?

Comment: What do you put in place of the `...` in the actual code is the most relevant part. Could you please show what's in your real code?

Comment: Varargs in Java is just syntactic sugar. The compiler turns `Object...` into `Object[]`. So yeah, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are calling the method, the reflection thinks that you are passing three individual parameters, rather than a single array parameter. Try this:

```
id = (String) m.invoke(adminTask, new Object[]{ new Object[] {"a", "b", "c"} });
```

Comment: Ack, I thought of trying this but didn't because it seemed too unlikely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Method m = adminTask.getClass().getMethod("createJDBCProvider", Object[].class);
id = (String) m.invoke(adminTask, new String[]{ "a", "b", "c" });
```

The signature of the method invoke is  `public Object invoke(Object obj, *Object... args*)` and Idea has an inspection that triggers when passing an array when a vararg of the same type is expected instead.